# Display both Metro and desktop apps at the same time in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Is it possible to display metro and desktop apps at the same time in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your resolution is set to 1366x768 or greater, you can use the snap feature to view two metro apps (or desktop and metro). You can do this by grabbing from the top of the screen and dragging an app over, or by using the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd>

Note though, that you cannot use desktop applications if the desktop is docked to a third of one side; you'll just see a list of thumbnails, then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply drag the metro app to one side of the screen (click and drag from the top to the side).